# Error with pandas.dt while extracting year from a date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, datetime

The data in test.csv are like this:

```
      TIMESTAMP                                           POLYLINE
0    1408039037  [[-8.585676,41.148522],[-8.585712,41.148639],[...
1    1408038611  [[-8.610876,41.14557],[-8.610858,41.145579],[-...
2    1408038568  [[-8.585739,41.148558],[-8.58573,41.148828],[-...
3    1408039090  [[-8.613963,41.141169],[-8.614125,41.141124],[...
4    1408039177      [[-8.619903,41.148036],[-8.619894,41.148036]]
..          ...                                                ...
315  1419171485  [[-8.570196,41.159484],[-8.570187,41.158962],[...
316  1419170802  [[-8.613873,41.141232],[-8.613882,41.141241],[...
317  1419172121  [[-8.6481,41.152536],[-8.647461,41.15241],[-8....
318  1419171980  [[-8.571699,41.156073],[-8.570583,41.155929],[...
319  1419171420  [[-8.574561,41.180184],[-8.572248,41.17995],[-...

[320 rows x 2 columns]
```

I read them from csv file in this way:

```
train  = pd.read_csv("path/train.csv",engine='python',error_bad_lines=False)
```

So, I have this timestamp in Unix format. I want to convert in UTC time and then extract year, month, day and so on.

This is the code for the conversion from Unix timestamp to UTC date time:

```
train["TIMESTAMP"] = [float(time) for time in train["TIMESTAMP"]]
train["data_time"] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time, datetime.timezone.utc) for time in train["TIMESTAMP"]]
```

To extract year and other information I do this:

```
train["year"] = train["data_time"].dt.year
train["month"] = train["data_time"].dt.month
train["day"] = train["data_time"].dt.day
train["hour"] = train["data_time"].dt.hour
train["min"] = train["data_time"].dt.minute
```

But I obtain this error when the execution arrives at the extraction point:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-d2249cabe965> in <module>()
 67 train["TIMESTAMP"] = [float(time) for time in train["TIMESTAMP"]]
 68 train["data_time"] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time, datetime.timezone.utc) for time in train["TIMESTAMP"]]
---> 69 train["year"] = train["data_time"].dt.year
  70 train["month"] = train["data_time"].dt.month
 71 train["day"] = train["data_time"].dt.day

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/accessors.py in __new__(cls, data)
478             return PeriodProperties(data, orig)
479 
--> 480         raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
 AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

I also read a lot of similiar discussion but I can't figure out why I obtain this error.

Edited:

So the train["TIMESTAMP"] data are like this:

```
1408039037
1408038611
1408039090
```

Then I do this with this data:

```
train["TIMESTAMP"] = [float(time) for time in train["TIMESTAMP"]]
train["data_time"] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time, datetime.timezone.utc) for time in train["TIMESTAMP"]]
train["year"] = train["data_time"].dt.year
train["month"] = train["data_time"].dt.month
train["day"] = train["data_time"].dt.day
train["hour"] = train["data_time"].dt.hour
train["min"] = train["data_time"].dt.minute
train = train[["year", "month", "day", "hour","min"]]
```

Comment: if working with pandas, use [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). e.g. here `pd.to_datetime(train["TIMESTAMP"], unit='s')`. btw. the `dt` accessor is a pandas thing, not related to numpy.

Comment: @MrFuppes Do you mean in the first or the second line of code?

Comment: @AndreaDiMartino, I am unable to repro your error, please add a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you more

Comment: I mean `train["data_time"] = pd.to_datetime(train["TIMESTAMP"], unit='s', utc=True)`, i.e. replace *both* lines.

Comment: Thanks to @MrFuppes I solved the problem